# Resolving a java.lang.NumberFormatException: error

Tags: java.util.scanner, numberformatexception

currently I'm getting java.lang.NumberFormatException:  error. I'm having trouble fixing it.

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
/**
  * Write a description of class Square here.
  * 
  * @author (your name) 
  * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Square {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner firstInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner secondInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String n = firstInput.next();
    n = n.replaceAll("[*0-9]","");
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n);


    int[] squares = new int[b];
    int[] squared = new int[b];

    for(int i = 0; i <= squares.length - 1; i++ ) {
        System.out.print("Write square number " + (i + 1) + " : " );
        squares[i] = secondInput.nextInt();
    }

    for(int j = 0; j <= squares.length - 1; j++) {
        squared[j] = squares[j] * squares[j];
    }

    System.out.print("The square of inputted numbers are: ");

    for(int k = 0; k <= squared.length - 1; k++) {
        System.out.print(squared[k] + " ");   
    }     
  }
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Square.main(Square.java:17)
```

Essentially the user input will be "java square 5" for example, and it'll detect the value 5, set the size of array as 5 and then it'll ask the person for 5 numbers he/she would like to square.

The prescribed above works when there are only integers, but the moment I put in a string, it stops working.

Any help would be appreciated!

note: I know my code is probably crappy, I'm still learning!

Comment: consider reducing your problem to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll maybe be able answer your question yourself. use the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to find out, why `Scanner.nextInt()` is throwing `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I have been looking into the documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one scanner. The two scanners are competing with each other to read from System.in. Then you need to scan twice to get the tokens "java" and "square". Then you can start looping to get the .nextInt()s.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.next(); // should be "java"
input.next(); // should be "square"
input.nextInt(); // should be 5
```

Comment: That does make sense, but could you perhaps dumb it down a little from where you said "you need to scan twice to get the tokens"?

Comment: I've updated the answer. By default, Scanner reads tokens separated by whitespace.